# Как выровнять символы в строке?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив строк. Нужно чтобы каждая строка начиналась с одного из наборов:

```
{"F+R|"," R |"," F |"}
```

но так, чтобы отступ слева был одинакового размера (в данном случае 4 символа).

Что должно получиться (пример):

```
 F |bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 R | bla...bla...bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
F+R| bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla
```

а получается

```
F |bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
R | bla...bla...bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
F+R| bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla bla...bla...bla
```

Строки выводятся в ListView (из EditText).

Comment: Попробуй у ListView - выставить моноширный* шрифт "Courier" или "Courier new"; Предварительно обработай текст (чтобы слева было 4 символа).

Comment: Попробуйте вместо пробела поставить неразрывный пробел `\u00A0`.

Comment: Замена пробелов не помогла. Моноширный шрифт сделал всю строку очень большой, а это не совсем то, что надо. Хотя конечно выравнивание достигнуто.

Comment: Android не показывает пробелы в начале строки что ли?

Comment: Показывает, но они не равны ширине символа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы поставить пробелы вначале текста, используйте [неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB) (код символа #00A0) - равен по ширине обычному пробелу или цифровой пробел (код символа #2007) - равен по ширине цифрам. Вариантов два, так как разные символы в шрифте имеют разную ширину и поэтому один обычный пробел не равен по ширине одной букве, соответственно выравнивания через пробелы добится не так просто. Возможным решением будет использование какого то моноширинного шрифта, где все символы равны по ширине.

Применительно к Android строка с ведущим неразрывным пробелом может выглядеть так:

```
"\u00A0 F | bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
```

с цифровым пробелом (этот вариант должен решить проблему):

```
"\u2007F\u2007| bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, заменить пробел другим символом - выход?

```
F_R|
_R_|
_F_|


F-R|
-R-|
-F-|
```